# How does one 'glue' together the different $k$-hilbert spaces to make them continuous in $k$?

Tags: condensed-matter, hilbert-space, topological-order

In a typical introduction to toplogical phase transitions via e.g. the SSH chain or the transverse-field Ising model, the agument around using the Berry phase usually proceeds as follows:

1. The periodic boundary Hamiltonian can be written as $$H =\sum_k H_k, \hspace{2em}k= \frac{2\pi n}{L}$$where each $H_k$ acts on some finite-dimensional Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$.
2. We let $L\to \infty$, and reinterpret $H_k$ as a map $\mathbb{R} \to GL(\mathcal{H})$.
3. The eigenstates of $H_k$ can be viewed as $U(1)$ bundle $E \to M$, where $M$ is the manifold formed by tracing out the path in $k$ space (which is homeomorphic to $S^1$). By giving this bundle the Berry connection, one finds that there is a topological distinction to be drawn between certain choices of $M$, i.e. certain parameter choices.

I'm wondering about step 2. Even with $L \to \infty$, there are still only countably many $k$-space points, and so the vector bundle of $k$s and phases $\{ k, \phi \}$ remains, topologically, $U(1)^N$. Further, on the basis of decoherence / lifetime broadening arguments one would expect there to be a certain "coarse graining" threshold in $k$ space below which the distinction between discrete and continuous $k$ is no longer meaningful, though I'm not sure on this point.

**In the context of real condensed matter systems, why should we expect the phases of $H_k$ eigenstates to vary smoothly, rather than jump between random phases? Further, is there a way to quantitatively capture the critical system size at which the efective continuum approximation becomes valid?**